# can derived class access base class non-static members without object of the base class

Tags: c++, derived-class, base-class, non-static

can derived class access base class non-static members without object of the base class

```
class base
{
public:
    int data;
    void f1()
    {
    
    }
};
class derived : base 
{
public :
     void f()
    {
        base::data = 44; // is this possible
        cout << base::data << endl;
    }
};
```

why does the below one shows a error

```
class base
{
public:
    int data;
    void f1()
    {
    
    }
};
class derived : base 
{
public :
     static void f()
    {
        base::data = 44; // this one shows a error
        cout << base::data << endl;
    }
};
```

i could not find the answer at any wedsites

Comment: `data` is a **instance** member variable. In the second code snippet, `f` is a *static* member  function. There is no active instance in a static member function. Thus, there is no `data` because there is no instance. The difference between instance vs. static members  is covered in *any* remedial text on the C++ language.

Comment: What would you expect it to mean to be able to access a non-static member of the class without an object of that class? Given that you understand what the difference is between non-static and static members is, why would you expect the second version to work at all?

Comment: `base::data = 44;` is actually `this->base::data = 44;` (as `data` is not `static`). and in `static` method as`f`, you cannot use `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your 1st example

```
class derived : base 
{
    void f()
    {
        base::data = 44;
    }
};
```

`f()` is not-static. It works on an object of `derived`, which includes an object of `base`. So, `base::data = 44;` is equivalent to `data = 44;` and it accesses the member of the object.

In the 2nd example

```
class derived : base 
{
    static void f()
    {
        base::data = 44;
    }
};
```

function `f()` is static, so it does not have access to any object. There, `base::data = 44;` could mean static `data` member of `base`. But because `data` is non-static, the expression is ill-formed.